# SQL LIKE query returning a row

Tags: sql

Why does the following query return one row:

```
select * from (
select 'th' As Test1) as Test
where Test1 like '%þ%'
```

I am using the following collation: `Latin1_General_CI_AS`

`þ` is being evaluated as `LIKE th`.

Comment: I think it is the collation. [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8561) Second query without the collation returns nothing which concludes your results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All your question are answered on [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_%28letter%29) at Wikipedia. The Thorn letter and the digraph `th` are considered to be the same in the collation you're using. It's similar in sound to the Greek theta character `θ`.

Comment: Thanks, the collation I use is: Latin1_General_CI_AS.  The following webpage tells me the code page is 1252: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186356(v=sql.100).aspx.  Here is the code page documentation from Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252.  T, H and Thorn are different characters?

Comment: @w0051977, in Icelandic, t, h and þ are considered distinct letters (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icelandic_language) - what I'm saying is that the collation coercion rules being followed here are treating the _sequence_ "th" and "þ" as identical. Since the collation you're using is case-insensitive, accent-sensitive, it's possibly the CI bit doing this.